# facebook tab not resizing any more

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anyone know if the code that resized the iframe of a facebook tab has chanhged recently?

I used to add this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{ 
   FB.Canvas.setSize( {height: 1040} );
}

// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() 
{
    FB.Canvas.setSize( {height: 1040} );
}
</script>
```

and this in the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
   FB.init({
      appId : '561492603881225',
      status : true, // check login stat
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml : true // parse XFBML 
});
</script>
```

and all that needed changing is the APP ID and the values in the setSize script then I could set the height to match the content on each tab.

However looking at my tabs now, all of them seem to have reset back to the default 800px high which makes me think facebook have changed the way they do things but can't find anything anywhere and have seen nothing on the developer blog.

Comment: I use the following "FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();" ??

Comment: I have read that too but it has never worked for me so setsize was always ok for me. just tried replacing it with setAutogrow but no luck??

Answer (score 0):

You first have to check whether the Canvas is loaded-

```
FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    console.log(response.time_delta_ms);
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```

[FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading/)

OR, you can also try after `onBodyLoad`

Comment: would this go in script tags before the other script in the head?

Comment: Use this after `FB.init()`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work without even setting a height, possibly a responsive solution?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
fb_root = document.createElement( 'div' );
fb_root.id = 'fb-root';
try
{
window.document.childNodes[0].appendChild( fb_root );
}
catch( error )
{
window.document.body.appendChild( fb_root );
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId  : '1375967019301812', //your app ID
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
});

//FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });

function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

var mySetSize = function() {
    var height = getDocHeight();
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: height });
    setTimeout( mySetSize, 200 );
};
setTimeout( mySetSize, 200 );
};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());


var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style'),
rules = document.createTextNode('body { position: relative; max-width:     520px!important;width: 520px!important; overflow: hidden!important; margin: 0px!important;     }');

style.type = 'text/css';
if(style.styleSheet)
style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
else style.appendChild(rules);
head.appendChild(style);

</script>
```